# Apple Developer account converting a .cer file to p12

Tags: ios, certificate, openssh, apple-developer, p12

So I created a `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest` and had it signed in Apple Developer portal, under `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Identifiers`.

And after I downloaded the result I have a `myCert.cer` file, now for my next step I need to somehow convert this to a `.p12` file. But openssh won't allow me to do this without the ".key" file. Apple Developer portal doesn't share with me. How can I output `.p12` from this step?

Answer (score 1):

After installation myCert.cer on your computer you need to find this certificate in Keychain Access -> click on certificate(right button on your mouse or double finger on your touchpad) -> click "Export ..." -> Save .p12 file.[image: Find certificate in Keychain Access] [image: Save .p12]

Comment: don't have this option

Answer (score 0):

After downloading myCert.cer file installs this in keychain access by a double tab. Then from keychain access, you can export your certificate in .p12 format.

Comment: what do you mean by "double tab"?